# How does map and mapValues work in this example?

Tags: scala

Below code transforms a string into its binary representation so

```
1 = 1,1,0,0
2 = 1,1,1,0
3 = 1,1,0,1
4 = 1,1,0,0

 Returns

4-->1100
1-->1100
2-->1110
3-->1101
```

The code :

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

object BinaryRepFunctional extends Application {
  val userDetails = HashMap("1" -> "ab",
                            "2" -> "abc",
                            "3" -> "abd",
                            "4" -> "ab")
  val lettersToCheck = "abcd"

  def getBinaryRepresentation = userDetails.mapValues(
      string => lettersToCheck.map(
          letter => if (string.contains(letter)) '1' else '0'))

  getBinaryRepresentation foreach ( (t2) => println (t2._1 + "-->" + t2._2))
}
```

This is the signature of mapValues :

```
override def mapValues[C](f: B => C): Map[A, C] = 
  new MappedValues(f) with DefaultMap[A, C]
```

This is the signature of Map, so it accepts a function paramater and applies this
function to every entry in the collection being called.

```
  def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
    def builder = { // extracted to keep method size under 35 bytes, so that it can be JIT-inlined
      val b = bf(repr)
      b.sizeHint(this)
      b
    }
    val b = builder
    for (x <- this) b += f(x)
    b.result
  }
```

Can the function getBinaryRepresentation be made more explicit as I'm having difficulty understanding how it works ?

Comment: mapValues is just like map but for values :) Map may be viewed as a list of pairs (key, value). So, when you just execute `map` - you transform a tuple `(key, value)`, but in `mapValues` you transform only a value. `mapValues(f)` is equivalent of `map { case (k, v) => k -> f(v) }`.

Comment: also note that `mapValues` is lazy: the resultant map is basically a skin over the previous one that applies the function to the existing value when or if it is accessed. So it takes less memory than `map`, and may or may not be more efficient, depending on how often the elements are accessed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't understand `getBinaryRepresentation`in its current form, is this perhaps because you're unfamiliar with functional programming concepts?

The `map` method typically takes a function from `A` to `B`, and applies it to each element of a collection of `A`s, in order to create a collection of `B`s.  For example, given a `Function1[Int, Int]` defined as `x => x + 1` (i.e. the increment operator), this could be mapped over a collection `[1, 7, 42]` to give [`2, 8, 43]`.  Or consider

```
val lengthFn: Function1[String, Int] = { s => s.length }
val myColl = List("London", "Paris")
myColl map lengthFn   // returns List(6, 5)
```

That's what map does.  `mapValues` is very similar - it's just a specialised version that acts on a `Map` and transforms each of the values in that Map.  So extending the example above:

```
val capitals = Map("England" -> "London", "France" -> "Paris")
capitals mapValues lengthFn    // returns Map("England" -> 6, "France" -> 5)
```

---

If you understand that, the definition of `getBinaryRepresentation` is straightforward.  It takes the `userDetails` map, and applies a transformation to each of its values (so the result will be a map with the same keys but different values).

The function applied to each value `string` is

```
lettersToCheck.map(letter => if (string.contains(letter)) '1' else '0'))
```

Once again this is applying a mapping, this time over the `lettersToCheck` list (a `String` is a `List[Char]`).  Each character in turn is transformed according to the function:

```
if (string.contains(letter)) '1' else '0'
```

and so each letter in the list is mapped to either `'1'` or `'0'`, depending on whether `string` contains it.  This means that the result of the map applied to each value will be a four-character string made up entirely of 1s and 0s, according to the letters contained within each key.

And so the result of the whole thing is a Map where the values are these four-character 1-and-0 strings as returned from the inner function.  It's straightforward when you get your head around it, but I can understand it would be confusing if you just follow through the lines of code in `map`'s implementation, without understanding what it *means*.

Answer (score 0):

Your `userDetails` map contains for each entry `1`, `2`, and so on, a representation of the result but with bits replaced by letters. For example for key `3` the value is `abd` which means that 1st, second and fourth bit from the left (1-based) should be set. The function `getBinaryRepresentation`goes through the letters `abcd`stored in `lettersToCheck` and for each of these letters, inserts into the result string `0` or `1` depending on whether that letter apears in the corresponding entry.

Given that the bit strings are at most 4 bits long, it would be much simpler to just store the strings of ones and zeroes directly in the map and avoid any translation altogether. Your code becomes then as simple as:

```
object BinaryRepFunctional extends Application {
  val userDetails = HashMap("1" -> "1100",
                        "2" -> "1110",
                        "3" -> "1101",
                        "4" -> "1100")
  userDetails foreach ( (t2) => println (t2._1 + "-->" + t2._2))
}
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but the example I gave is contrived in order to ask a simpler question of a much larger problem.